# Read rosbag in python at timestamp

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I use python and and want to read rosbag data at the data timestamp.
Is there a routine to do that or should I generate delay after each read corresponding to the duration to the next timestamp ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416211/read-rosbag-in-python-at-timestamp/) by [dev4all12358](https://answers.ros.org/users/67329/dev4all12358/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2023-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are asking how to publish messages stored in a rosbag file in "real time" using the rosbag API, then yes, your code must insert an appropriate delay between read calls.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2